# Android layout by layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How could i achive next one after another layouts position (with height)?

[image]

Current code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Новая заметка"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please clearify what you mean with 'layout by layout'?

Comment: I'd like layouts have height positions like table rows in a table. I mean, Layout height1 + Layout height2 = Activity Height (one after another)

Comment: Indeed, it's not completely clear what is meant by "layout by layout", but your picture's layout can be easily achieved through using one parent `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and two children (`ListView` and `Button`) with weights specified.

Comment: @Android777, yeah, but looks like i couldn't use `layout_alignParentBottom` with LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to since `LinearLayout` in with `android:orientation` = "vertical" layouts its children in rows, and specifying weights for them will make them occupy the whole screen. Actually, I believe setting weight for just one child should be enough for this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myButton">

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="New Note"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Because I don't see the reason to put relative layout insid another relative layout.

Comment: Looks like i need just `android:layout_above` to achive my goal

Comment: Still, `RelativeLayout` is a waste for basic vertical layouts :) It was made to reduce the number of levels (`LinearLayout`s) in complex layouts, because two levels of `LinearLayout` are considered worse than one level of `RelativeLayout`, but apparently one level of `RelativeLayout` is heavier to layout than one level of `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same layout when you will add "layout_above" property use this code.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Новая заметка"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But you don't really need second level `RelativeLayout`s, their attributes can be put into the final views. Now they just increase your layout drawing time.

Comment: @Android777 you are right, but I just answered the question he asked which were to add two layouts, anyways thanks for your comment..

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of what is needed, there's little need for relative layout at all. It can be achieved with just `LinearLayout`, which is less expensive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="New Note"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```